# Django - Error models with control data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I'm working on writing the models.py file, and I need some controls to perform the automatic compilation of some fields.

```
MOTIVOINGRESSO = (
         (u'sequestro ', u'sequestro'),
         (u'fermo ', u'fermo'),
         (u'confisca final ', u'confisca final'),
         (u'cambio custodian ', u'cambio custodian'),
     )
     motivo_ingresso = models.CharField (max_length = 50, choices = MOTIVOINGRESSO)
```

FERMO = (
         (u'30 ', u'30'),
         (u'60 ', u'60'),
         (u'90 ', u'90'),
         (u'180 ', u'180'),
         (u'1 month ', u'1 month'),
         (u'3 months, 'u'3 months'),
         (u'indeterminato ', u'indeterminato'),
     )
     durata_in_giorni_del_fermo = models.CharField (max_length = 20, choices = STOPPED, blank = True)

If the administrator the choice click '*sequestro*', in `durata_in_giorni_del_fermo` will automatically selected '*indeterminato*'.
Should I report the values ​​entered? or machine cycles if within the models?

Any Ideas?

Comment: You can do this by `ajax` request on form fields.

Comment: ajax? any link for resolve this problem, and resolve in ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very easy if you will do it through `Jquery` in template. I don't know, this can be possible in `models.py`. Below links are much relevant to your question.

1. [How to implement two dropdowns dependent on each other using Django and jQuery](http://blog.devinterface.com/2011/02/how-to-implement-two-dropdowns-dependent-on-each-other-using-django-and-jquery/)
2. [Dynamic select fields with JQuery and django](http://formerlyconversal.wordpress.com/2009/11/01/dynamic-select-fields-with-jquery-and-django/)

Hoping you will got the idea about ajax and Jquery after following above links :)