# limit choices for foreign field based on other field

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possible to do really dynamic form in AdminModel? I have following models:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    firstfield=models.ForeignKey(First)
    secondField= models.ForeignKey(Second, blank=True,null=True)
    #some other fields

class Second(models.Model):
    firstfield=models.ForeignKey(First)
    #other fields
```

As you can see Second is optional. But I want it to limit according to current selection in First? It would require some page refreshing or some ajax work but I simply don't know how to even pass First value. Maybe I should add it to request and then use something similar to:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey ?

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341768/django-error-models-with-control-data/11356230#11356230

Comment: I would never find this (by description of a problem) but links proposed in solution there seems to be very usefull!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it through `ajax` request. If you don't know how it works see the below links.

1. [How to implement two dropdowns dependent on each other using Django and jQuery](http://blog.devinterface.com/2011/02/how-to-implement-two-dropdowns-dependent-on-each-other-using-django-and-jquery/)
2. [Dynamic select fields with JQuery and django](http://formerlyconversal.wordpress.com/2009/11/01/dynamic-select-fields-with-jquery-and-django/)

Comment: As this kind of question is already been answered but the question title is not much related to its description. So that' why I posted the same answer here again.